# java.lang.Class#newInstance for Type Parameterized Class w/ Manifest

Tags: scala

Given the following:

```
scala> trait Parent
trait Parent

scala> class Foo[A <: Parent](implicit m: scala.reflect.Manifest[A]) {}
defined class Foo
```

I create a new instance.

```
scala> new Foo()
res1: Foo[Nothing] = Foo@226f1597
```

And then try `Class#newInstance` without success.

```
scala> res1.getClass
res2: Class[_ <: Foo[Nothing]] = class Foo

scala> res1.getClass.newInstance
java.lang.InstantiationException: Foo
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:364)
```

For a class with a `manifest`, is there any way to use `Class#newInstance`?

(I'm asking since my parameterized class (with a manifest) extends `akka.microkernel.Bootable`, which requires a no-arg constructor).

Comment: Not sure I understand. Do you want an instance of `Foo`, or `A`?

Comment: Well, I need to make a new Foo. I need the `manifest` since I call a method that needs a `manifest`. In order to call a method, `def foo[A <: ...](implicit m: Manifest[A] = { ... }`, I need, I assume, to pass it a type parameter.

Comment: What's the purpose of the type parameter then?

Comment: well, `foo` contains a call to construct a new class, `class Bar[A <: Parent](...)(implicit m: scala.reflect.Manifest[A])`. So, without that type parameter, the `m.runtimeClass` will be `Nothing`, I think but am not sure...

Comment: I need the type parameter since the underlying `A`, i.e. the class, gets used. example: `def f[A <: Parent](implicit m: Manifest[A]) = { m.runtimeClass.getName } `.

Comment: I think the problem is that the implicit makes it *not* a no-arg constructor, which `newInstance` needs to work.

Comment: yeah, definitely @m-z. And I don't see how I can `map` over a `Set[Class[A]]` to get a `Set[Foo[A]]`.

Comment: So why not provide a manifest to the method directly instead of making it a part of `Foo`? It's really very simple: `newInstance` (and `Bootable`) requires no-argument constructor; your class doesn't have a no-argument constructor.

Comment: I am getting a similar error while doing something with reflection and Scala. I could not get the source. The error is the same `java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:364)`. But when I look at `Class.java` online line 364 has something else. Did you check the source.

Comment: I actually don't have that laptop anymore to check. But I recall that it was on JDK7.